dotnet build command on a non-SDK project doesn't generate Entity Framework *.csdl, *.ssdl and *.msl files
This is a continuation question to:
"Unable to load the specified metadata resource" after building using dotnet build
After finding the root cause for the problem, but not the solution:
I have a .NET 4.7.2 project which uses Entity Framework v4. This EF uses an .edmx file.
My problem is that when I use the CLI command:
dotnet build 

or even
dotnet msbuild

the *.csdl, *.ssdl and *.msl files are not generated as they should (checked and verified it using  a reflector tool - dotPeek).
When building the project in Visual Studio, there is no problem and the files are being generated.
I could not use a
msbuild 

cli command (which would probably do the work) because there are other projects which my current project relies on and those projects are SDK projects types which cannot be built with msbuild.
